# Read data from Google Cloud Datastore by dialogflow agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am newbie in the chatbot domain. I need to develop a dialogflow chatbot which can store the data collected from user to Google Cloud Datastore Entities(not Firebase real time database) and retrieve it back when the user want to search.

I can able to write the data collected from user to datastore. But I am struggling in retrieving the data. I am writing the function in the dialogflow inline editor.

Write function :

```
  function order_pizza(agent) {
     var pizza_size = agent.parameters.size;
     var pizza_topping = agent.parameters.pizza_topping;
     var date_time = agent.parameters.size;
     const taskKey = datastore.key('order_item');
     const entity = {
       key: taskKey,
       data: {
       item_name: 'pizza',
       topping: pizza_topping,
       date_time: date_time,
       order_time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
       size: pizza_size }
      };
     return datastore.save(entity).then(() => {
               console.log(`Saved ${entity.key.name}: ${entity.data.item_name}`);
               agent.add(`Your order for ${pizza_topping} pizza has been placed!`);

            });
}
```

where "order_item" is the kind(table in datastore) the data is being stored. It is storing the data successfully.

Read data:(the function not working)

```
  function search_pizza(agent){
    const taskKey = datastore.key('order_item');
    var orderid = agent.parameters.id;
    const query = datastore.createQuery('taskKey').filter('ID','=', orderid);
    return datastore.runQuery(query).then((result) =>{
    agent.add(result[0]);
    });
    
  }
```

This is what i tried so far! Whereever i search I can find the result for firebase realtime database. But can't find solution for google datastore!
Followed many tutorial. But can't quite get it right! Kindly help!

Comment: Could you share the documentation you were following or the resources?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to do with taskKey in search_pizza. Is taskKey a kind or an incomplete key for an entity you intend to write.  You may want to try `datastore.createQuery('order_item').filter('ID','=', orderid);` in search_pizza.